# unchecking checked check boxes using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need write a function that will "uncheck" the old "checked" boxes with in a group. Basically, are group A and group B and once items from group A is checked and submitted, it shows the items from group A and same thing with group B. But the issue is when item from group A is selected and displayed and you do the same thing from group B. The items form group A still shows up. is there any built in function in jQuery that will do the trick. The code is set up at http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/mJgcK/

HTML

```
<h1>Find Services You Need</h1>
<select class="selectOne">
<option>Please Select One</option>
<option name="one">Basic Needs</option>
<option name="two">Disabilities Services for Adults</option>

</select><!--selectOne-->



<div class="options">
<div class="option one">
    <h3>Basic Needs</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="oneA">Employment services<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="oneB">Financial assistance<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="oneC">Food<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="oneD">Housing<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="oneE">Legal issues<br>
</div><!--optionOne-->

<div class="option two">
    <h3>Disabilities Services for Adults </h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="twoA">Advocacy<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="twoB">Coordinated Care<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="twoC">Employment Support<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="twoD">Housing<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="twoE">Recreation & Social Activities<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="twoF">Referrals & Financial Options<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="twoG">Services for the Deaf and Hard of Hearing<br>
</div><!--optionOne-->


</div><!--options-->

<div id="showMeContainer"><div id="showMe">Show Me</div>

</div><!--button-->


<div class="answers">
<div class="answerTitle"><h3>Title Here</h3></div><!--answerTitle-->

<div class="one">

    <div class="oneA answer">
        <p>Employment services</p>
    </div><!--oneA-->
    <div class="oneB answer" >
        <p>Financial assistance</p>
    </div><!--oneB-->
    <div class="oneC answer">
        <p>Food</p>        
    </div><!--oneC-->
    <div class="oneD answer">
        <p>Housing</p>
    </div><!--oneD-->
    <div class="oneE answer">
        <p>Legal Issues</p>
    </div><!--oneE-->
</div><!--answer-->

<div class="two">
    <div class="twoA answer">
        <p>Advocacy</p>
    </div><!--oneA-->
    <div class="twoB answer" >
        <p>Cordinated Care</p>
    </div><!--oneB-->
    <div class="twoC answer">
        <p>Employment Support</p>        
    </div><!--oneC-->
    <div class="twoD answer">
        <p>Housing</p>
    </div><!--oneD-->
    <div class="twoE answer">
        <p>Recreation & Social Activities</p>
    </div><!--oneE-->
    <div class="twoF answer">
        <p>Referrals & Financial Options</p>
    </div><!--oneF-->
    <div class="twoG answer">
        <p>Services for the Deaf and Hard of Hearing</p>
    </div><!--oneF-->
</div><!--two-->


</div><!--answers-->​
```

And the jQuery 1.2.6 (I don't have privilege to use newer version)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.option').hide();//Hiding all options
$('.answer').hide(); //Hiding all the answers   
$('#showMeContainer').hide(); //Hiding the show me button
$('.answerTitle').hide();


$('.selectOne').change(function(event){


    var name = $('.selectOne option:selected').attr('name');
    //alert(name);
    $('#showMeContainer').hide(); 
    $('.option').hide();
    $('.' + name).show();
    $('#showMeContainer').show(); 


});

$('#showMe').click(function(event) {  
    $('.answer').hide();
    $('.answerTitle').hide();
    var checked = $('.option').find(':checked');
    $.each(checked, function() {
        var name = this.name;
        $('.' + name).show();
         $('.answerTitle').show();

    });

    var x = $('#compBody').height() + 50;// Getting the height on the div
    $('#pageBody').css('height',x); // updating the height of the outer div

});
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following line

```
$(".options [type=checkbox]").attr('checked', false);
```

In `$('.selectOne').change()`

That will uncheck all checkboxes when the list selection changes.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mJgcK/7/)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you still looking for the answer, but you can see it in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mJgcK/61/)

I just connected each check-box with its click event that way you can remove the other group's selected checkboxes that way they can select any group without worry about the checkboxes being deselected